# Access local Apache Server (XAMPP) over Internet with Android-App

Tags: php, android, apache, xampp

I'm devoloping an android application, that calls a PHP-file on my XAMPP apache server. When testing local using `http://10.0.2.2/path/file.php` it al works fine.
When I try to call it from my smartphone it doesn't work. I changed the address to my external IP `http://xx.xx.xx.xx/path/file.php` and forwarded the port 80 to my PC's local address port 80. But it still won't work.

```
    public ArrayList<Spieler> getAllSpieler() {
    ArrayList<Spieler> alleSpieler = new ArrayList<Spieler>();
    // PHP-Datei aufrufen
    String url = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/langenacht/getAllSpieler.php";
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //use returned values
}
```

This works on the AVD and if I call http://xx.xx.xx.xx/langenacht/getAllSpieler.php in my Browser it also works (only if I'm in the wifi of my router that has the external IP), but not when I try it on my phone. My AVD is currently running android 2.2 because I keep getting an error when I try to use android 4.x
My HTC ONE has android 4.3. The App crashes when it fails to load the data but it normally should just leave the spinners empty.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_spieler_auswaehlen);

        spinnerSpielerAuswaehlen = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerSpielerAuswaehlen);
        ArrayList<Spieler> alleSpieler = strafenverwaltungsinstanz.getAllSpieler();

        String[] spielerliste = new String[alleSpieler.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < spielerliste.length; i++) {
            spielerliste[i]=alleSpieler.get(i).getVorname()+" "+alleSpieler.get(i).getNachname();
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSpieler = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spielerliste);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapterSpieler
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinnerSpielerAuswaehlen.setAdapter(adapterSpieler);

        //and so on
}
```

Comment: connect android phone via wifi to your lan use 10.0.2.2/path/file.php ?? profit

Comment: I want to use the app everywhere and not only when I'm in my wifi.
Weird thing is it know works on my emulator with my external IP but still doesn't work on my phone.

Comment: when you want to use it everywhere put it on a proper web server on the internets don't use your broadband :(

Comment: It's an app I need to code as an exam and I don't want to pay for a webserver for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used AsyncTasks to realize the calls to my Apache server it works fine now.